# seal character identification request is anybody on here qualified to do so thanks

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters, classical-chinese, seal, old-chinese

seal identification request [image][![enter image description here]seal identification request [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtmAr.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtmAr.jpg)part of the seal on a painting various experts cannot translate the writing symbols is anybody on here qualified to do so thanks ][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bcct.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bcct.jpg)which require identification is anybody on here qualified to do so because various specialists are unable to thanks

Comment: The upper word seems "若" to me.

Comment: @WarrenHiffington Please stop this nonsense, and put some effort into your questions.  This site is not your personal rubbish bin.

Comment: @r13, yes, it’s more likely the character “若”  my apologies 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 It is my lucky guess, never mind :)

Comment: @r13, a guess  you’re so modesty lah 

Comment: The characters are 若珣.

Answer (score 1):

Both the upper signature and the seal are  "若珣"， which could possibly be a woman's first name.